# Left Join no devuelve null values en PHPmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Buenas, estoy probando de hacer esta query:

```
SELECT 
    consulta.id_consulta,actu_consulta.fecha_actu 
FROM 
    consulta LEFT JOIN actu_consulta
       ON consulta.id_consulta=actu_consulta.id_consulta_actu
```

Y lo curioso es que esta query en el workbench me devuelve todos los valores.
Y si la pruebo en el phpmyadmin me devuelve solo los valores en que la `fecha_actu` no esté *null*.

Me gustaria saber cual es el problema que me está sucediendo.
Gracias

TABLAS:

```
 create table consulta
(id_consulta int not null auto_increment primary key,
codigo_web long,
usuario_creado int not null,
usuario_cerrado int,
fecha_creacion datetime,
fecha_cierre datetime,
estado_consulta boolean DEFAULT '0',
nombre varchar(15),
email varchar(50),
telf varchar(9),
localidad varchar(25),
idioma varchar(10),
descripcion text,
solucion text,  
capacidad_aula int,
dia_alquiler varchar(10),
tipo_contacto varchar(10),
tipo_consulta  varchar(10),
curso varchar(50),
cp varchar(10));

create table actu_consulta
(id_consulta_actu int not null auto_increment primary key,
id_usuario_actu int not null,
fecha_actu datetime,
descripcion text,
id_consulta int not null,
constraint fk_consulta_actu_consulta foreign key(id_consulta) references  consulta(id_consulta));
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el diseño de tu tabla `actu_consulta`?

Comment: create table actu_consulta
(id_consulta_actu int not null auto_increment primary key,
id_usuario_actu int not null,
fecha_actu datetime,
descripcion text,
id_consulta int not null,
constraint fk_consulta_actu_consulta foreign key(id_consulta) references consulta(id_consulta));

Comment: ¿Probaste a hacerlo sin `LEFT JOIN`? Es decir, cambiando el `LEFT JOIN` por una `,` y cambiando el `ON` por un `WHERE`

Comment: Si, y tampoco me ha funcionado. El problema es que necesito que devuelva todos los valores, aunque el campo fecha_actu esté vacío

Comment: Por cierto, en tu definición de la tabla `actu_consulta` a la hora de hacer la foreign key deberías de poner `foreign key(id_consulta_actu)`. Prueba a ver si es ese tu problema

Comment: Estas seguro? tengo la tabla consulta en la que id_consulta tiene una clave foránea que es id_consulta_actu. Un 1 -> N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en la última línea de tu SQL, pues estás relacionado los ids de tu 1ª tabla con la clave primaria de la 2ª:

```
       ON consulta.id_consulta=actu_consulta.id_consulta_actu
```

¿La clave que debe hacer referencia a tus consultas en la segunda tabla no debe ser **id_consulta**?

Por tanto, la parte final debería quedar así:

```
   ON consulta.id_consulta=actu_consulta.id_consulta
```

Comment: ojo clinico! =)